# Curve material mapping

Tags: rendering, geometry-nodes, fcurves

How can I mix/blend two different materials along the curve?
and then instance this curve to geometry.

Thanks, guys

Comment: pls add a sketch/screenshot, how it should look like for clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Elaborate, that are you going to achieve. What you have done, what you want to do and what makes you stuck

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this, but i think you want something else...so adding a sketch how it should look like would really help...

[image]

Comment: Thanks But I mean blend the materials along the curve from 1 to 100